# Why richtextblock not supported?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to add richtextblock to my project in Xaml .NETFrameWork 4.7

and I'm getting errors-

[image: print screen]

It's important to note that I can not find it in the toolbox, should it be there?

I googled I did not find any place that says something needs to be installed, I would love for you to help me

Thank you

Comment: It is under `Windows.UI` namespace for UWP projects. I think it is not supported in WPF yet. maybe you can use `RichTextBox`.

Comment: How can I use HtmlTextBlock https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlTextBlock/ ?

Comment: The definition in nuget says _HtmlTextBlock is a light-weighted WPF control that allow you to display rich text, by translating html like tags into TextBlock.Inlines._ so my guess is you need to supply HTML-similar formatted text to `HtmlTextBlock`.

Comment: By the way HtmlTextBlock is last updated on 6/7/2014, so it may be an abandoned project. It might not be the best idea to use it in a project that is planned to continue in the future.

Comment: For long and advanced formatted text in WPF, the best way is to incorporate flow documents : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 If your content is just few sentences, you can try `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Using a `RichTextBox` control in a WPF app requires the use of [XAML Islands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)

Comment: You can use the normal WPF `TextBlock`. It is the equivalent of the `RichTextBlock`. You can add rich content by handling the `TextBlock.Inlines` property.